# Saving states according to an indicator, perhaps by using the Retain statement

Tags: sas

As can bee seen, I sorted the data by rk, and descending version:

```
data have;
rk = 1;
version = 7;
ind = 0;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 6;
ind = 1;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 5;
ind  = 0;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 4;
ind = 0;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 3;
ind = 1;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 2;
ind = 0;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 1;
ind = 0;
output;
rk = 1;
version = 0;
ind = 0;
output;
run;
```

I thought of the Retain statement. but any solution for this problem will suit me just fine.
What I need to do is,
if at some point, ind  = 1, I want all previous rows (versions) for the same rk, to have some sort of indication for that.

So basically,
versions 0,1,2 should be flagged, because version 3 has ind = 1;

versions 4,5 should be flagged , because version 6 has ind = 1;

but version 7 should not be affected at all, as it appears after rows of ind = 1,
and not before them.

It would be even better if every flagged row affected by a row with ind = 1
will have an indicator states the version number affected that change,
meaning 
versions 0,1,2 will have a field named "affected_by" equals to 3
versions 4,5 will have that field equals to 6

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want all "previous" rows? Because right now your data set looks like this: http://puu.sh/5M7Mj.png  which seems more like you would be wanting all subsequent rows (after).

Comment: Well, I sorted the data that way because I thought it is a part of the solution... You can of course sort it however you think is appropriate.  I do want all "previous rows". Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data set was sorted, we will go "forward" (which I think is easier) using your sorted set. We'll use the `SELECT` statement as we only want one execution per iteration. We'll also use `RETAIN` statement that you have suggested and the `CAT` function for concatenating strings together to generate the indicator `flag`:

```
data test;
    set have;
    drop N count x;

    select;
        when(ind = 1) do;
            N = 1;
            count = version;
            retain N count;
            output;
        end;

        when(N = 1) do;

            x = ind;
            flag = cat('Flagged because of version ', count);
            N = .;
            retain x count;
            output;
        end; 

        when(x = ind) do;
            flag = cat('Flagged because of version ', count);
            retain x count;
            output;
        end;
        otherwise do;
            output;
        end;
    end;

run;
```

OUTPUT:

```
                   rk    version    ind                flag

                    1       7        0
                    1       6        1
                    1       5        0     Flagged because of version 6
                    1       4        0     Flagged because of version 6
                    1       3        1
                    1       2        0     Flagged because of version 3
                    1       1        0     Flagged because of version 3
                    1       0        0     Flagged because of version 3
```

In this case, `N` is used as an indicator for which the previous observation had ind = 1. Then we destroy it (i.e. N = .), otherwise it will just satisfy the N = 1 condition again in next iteration.

Note that we retain the variables `x` and `count` for comparing `x` with next `ind`. Variable `count` equals the version in the row that has ind = 1. For the flag indicator, use the `CAT` function to add the numeric variable `count` to a string.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. I took a SAS Base Programming course at college/university that preps for the SAS Institute Certified Professional (Base Programming) Examination. But I have not taken the exam yet.. 


   Most of the stuff I learned was from reading SAS papers online especially the Global Forum papers. I have actually never read a SAS book because I think it's a rip-off since they're the only company making the books. And I have some programming experience in C, Matlab and Python, so it makes SAS a bit easier to learn.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. Could you please mention the difference between a regular If statement and the Select statement you used?

Comment: In this case, recall that the data step is a loop. If we have a bunch of if statements in one data step loop, then they'll all be evaluated in each iteration, unless we use a RETURN statement in each if condition. But with the SELECT statement, after one when() condition is met and it's consequent is executed, it will leave the whole select statement without evaluating the other subsequent when() conditions.

Comment: Thank you for that. It works just fine with one indicator. Problem is, I have like 8 indicator fields and for each and every one of them I need to do the exact thing. I tried doing it myself, and ofcourse couldn't get it work... I assume the Select statement won't work in this case...

Comment: Hmmm. In the first when condition, instead of when(ind=1), change it to when(ind in (ind1,ind2,ind3,...)). E.g. when(ind in (1,2,3,4)) for your indicator numbers. Try and see if it works.